# Vertically center <option> and <button> in one line <div>

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document in which there is a top bar which contains some icons. The top bar only is one line and everything in it should be vertically centered.

Now I wanted to add a `<option>` and a `<button>` to the top bar but I can't figure out how to vertically center it in the top bar which is a div.

#### [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op28oohx/6/)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Yes, of course, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/op28oohx/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vertical Centering https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

I would use flexbox centering in this case (if you're okay with this browser-support list https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```
#topbar{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @MK added a note for this

Answer (score 1):

All of the items in `topbar` are `inline-block`s you can use `vertical-align: middle` to make them at the center.

I've putted `vartical-align: middle` on the `#topbar img` & `#topbar .separator`

```css
#topbar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #e0e0e0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#topbar img {
  height: auto;
  width: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#topbar .separator {
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Perfektes_Rechteck.svg" />
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <select>
        <option value="b">Build and Run</option>
        <option value="h">Build to HTML</option>
        <option value="e">Build Executable</option>
      </select>
  <button>Start</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace display: inline-block; with display: inline-flex; in the top bar css.